# css code for alternate windows safari fonts

Tags: css, windows, safari, google-webfonts

http://alleystoeden.org/testing3/index.html

in windows safari 5.1.7, the primary navigation, both regular and when hovered don't look right. in fact, when not hovering the main menu is practically unreadable it's so light. the drop down menu is fine and fonts there are rendering properly.

body text (visible on the contact form page) are also rendering correctly.

i've tested it on iphone and it is fine there.

is there some code i can add to this template to fix the windows safari font problem with just the primary menu?

i'm not sure what part of the code i would copy and paste to show what i'm currently using, but if you can tell me the name, i can copy and paste it here.

thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file (styles.css, line 1197) you have the following declaration:

```
white .nav--primary > li > a {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

Change this light grey to a darker colour and you should be fine.

Comment: the color looks great on all other devices and browsers. how would i change it just for windows safari? mac safari and ipad/iphone safari display fine.